# logback LogstashSocketAppender include environment variable in output

Tags: logstash, logback

Can you include the value of an environment variable in the json output when using the logback **LogstashSocketAppender**?

e.g. How would I include the value of an environment variable named `FOO` with every log message?  Would it look something like this?

`<appender name="SOCKET" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashSocketAppender">
  <host>127.0.0.1</host>
  <port>1511</port>
  <provider class="net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.LoggingEventPatternJsonProvider">
    <pattern>
      {
      "foo": "???"
      }
    </pattern>
  </provider>
</appender>`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

`<appender name="SOCKET" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashSocketAppender">
  <host>127.0.0.1</host>
  <port>1511</port>
  <customFields>
      {
      "foo": "???"
      }
  </customFields>
</appender>`

[See here for reference](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder)